# How to convert a char array to a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, json.net, getjson

How to convert this below string to JSON format this is for my project please anybody help me

```
{ "qty" : "2","name" : "ice cream","price" : "25"},
{ "qty" : "5","name" : "biriyani","price" : "250"},
{ "qty" : "1","name" : "kappa","price" : "50"}
```

I want to convert this data to an JSON data, sometimes this array will be huge that time also want to set JSON automatically in JavaScript or jQuery please help me

Comment: Isn't that json already? Wrap it in an array so it turns a JSON array `[{ "qty" : "2","name" : "ice cream","price" : "25"},{ "qty" : "5","name" : "biriyani","price" : "250"},{ "qty" : "1","name" : "kappa","price" : "50"}]`

Comment: [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) is what you need to convert a string to JSON. and [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for converting JSON to string.

Comment: You could have just googled String to JSON in javascript and you would have found it right away.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JSON.parse`:

```
JSON.parse('[{ "qty" : "2","name" : "ice cream","price" : "25"},{ "qty" : "5","name" : "biriyani","price" : "250"},{ "qty" : "1","name" : "kappa","price" : "50"}]')
```

Notice that I addded square brackets around your string since there are three objects in it.

Comment: sir, that data is coming from database to ajax page so everytime it will be different so what to do ?

Comment: add the square brackets to the string you retrieve from database, and feed the result to JSON.parse: `JSON.parse('['+string_from_database+']')`